# knowing when checkedtextiew is clicked

Tags: android, click

I have dynamically created checkedtextview of all the installed apps.  I would like to know how to know when the user taps the checkedtextview.  I have searched and cannot find it or did not understand the solution.  Can someone give me an example?

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            CheckedTextView ctv = new CheckedTextView(this);
            ctv.setText(packageInfo.packageName);
            ctv.setCheckMarkDrawable (android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);
            ctv.setHeight(80);
            ctv.setTextSize(35);
            ll.addView(ctv);
    }
    this.setContentView(sv);
```

This does what I what but does not seem like the correct way?

```
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            CheckedTextView ctv = new CheckedTextView(this);
            ctv.setText(packageInfo.packageName);
            ctv.setCheckMarkDrawable (android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);
            ctv.setHeight(80);
            ctv.setTextSize(35);
            ctv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
                @Override 
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        // Toggle the checked state of the button 
                        CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) v;
                        if (ctv.isSelected()) {
                            ctv.setSelected(false);
                            ctv.setCheckMarkDrawable(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);

                        } else { 
                            ctv.setSelected(true);
                            ctv.setCheckMarkDrawable(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);

                        } 
                    } 
                    return true; 
                } 
            });


            ll.addView(ctv);
    }
    this.setContentView(sv);
```

Comment: Is this Android? If so, you should tag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To notice when a view is clicked you should use a [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html).

```
ctv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help,  Would this be in the for loop.  I edit m my question above before I saw your answer.  looks like it works.

Comment: It depends. You can have it in the loop if you want a separate OnClickListener for each button, or you could create one OnClickListener outside the loop and add it inside the loop. If you use one you can use `view.getId()` to identify the button that clicked. Also, to clean up the code you could create a separate class that implements OnClickListener.

Comment: Great, I went with the separate class.  Thank you